# Python Recursion (Tower of Hanoi)

Tags: python, recursion

I'm new to python and experienced a problem that ist probably really easy to solve.

```py
def req_steps(num_disks):
    # implement this function
    if num_disks == 0:
        return 1 
    return 2 * req_steps(num_disks-1)

print("For moving {} disks, {} steps are required.".format(3, req_steps(3)))
```

The function should be (2^n)-1 and I can't get the -1 to work... It has to be a recursive function.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

The ultimate formula is = `(2^(num_of_disks))-1`
this means, `num_of_disks = 3` should give `7` which is `(2*2*2-1)` moves.

Comment: Why do you think your program doesn't work? You should update your question with examples of input and output to show this.

Comment: updatet it, it's the tower of hanoi function btw

Answer (score 1):

You may give the final answer `f(n) = 2^n-1`, which is a general fomula, while the question requests you to use the recurrence formula `f(n) = f(n-1) + 1 + f(n-1) when n > 1`.

```py
    def req_steps(num_disks):
        if num_disks == 1:
            return 1
        else:
            return 1 + 2 * req_steps(num_disks - 1)
    
    print("For moving {} disks, {} steps are required.".format(3, req_steps(3)))
```

which outputs:

```
For moving 3 disks, 7 steps are required.
```

The below recurrence fomula means when you want to move n disks from A to C (Suppose the 3 rods placing disks are named A, B and C), you can:

1. move n-1 disks from A to B, which takes f(n-1) steps
2. move the nth disk from A to C, which takes 1 step
3. move the n-1 disks from B to C, which takes f(n-1) steps

Comment: That's not the problem. The problem is that there is missing a -1 in the formula. its "(2^(num_of_disks))-1, which means for 3 it should give 7 (2*2*2-1)

Comment: @Orsons Thanks for reminding, I've modified the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works perfectly and the makes sense now!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the calculation is an upside down binary representation of the formula.

This code:

```py
def req_steps(num_disks):
    if num_disks <= 1:
        return 1 
    return 2 * req_steps(num_disks - 1) + 1

for n in range(2,7):
    print(n, req_steps(n))
```

produces:

```
2 3
3 7
4 15
5 31
6 63
```

The base case of `num_disks==1` returns `1`, but the previous recursion multiplies this by two, and adds 1. So as the recursion unfolds again it is producing a binary 1 in each binary digit place according to `num_disks` passed in by the original caller.